# VLC 1.2 mosaic streaming

Tags: vlc, mosaic

This VLM Config works in VLC 1.1, but I am having other issues with memory leaks after the player is running a mosaic for more than an hour.
I have installed VLC 1.2 but it fails to display any streams in the mosaic (see errors below). Individual streams work fine and I am using MMSH to stream WMV files.
From what I understand fake:// access method has been deprecated in VLC 1.2. Are there any other changes that would prevent this mosaic from working in VLC 1.2?

```
new bg broadcast enabled
setup bg output #bridge-in{offset=10}:display

#VLC 1.2
setup bg input "http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/4131/rainbowbackgroundq.png"

#OR- VLC 1.1
setup bg input 'fake://' option 'fake-file=http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/4131/rainbowbackgroundq.png' option 'fake-width=800' option 'fake-height=600'


setup bg option sub-filter=mosaic
setup bg option mosaic-alpha=255
setup bg option mosaic-height=600
setup bg option mosaic-width=800
setup bg option mosaic-align=5
setup bg option mosaic-xoffset=0
setup bg option mosaic-yoffset=0
setup bg option mosaic-vborder=5
setup bg option mosaic-hborder=5
setup bg option mosaic-position=1
setup bg option mosaic-rows=1
setup bg option mosaic-cols=2
setup bg option no-mouse-events
setup bg option no-keyboard-events
setup bg option no-audio
setup bg option mosaic-order=v1,v2
setup bg option no-mosaic-keep-picture
setup bg option no-mosaic-keep-aspect-ratio

new v1 broadcast enabled
setup v1 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/b2974e0a-24c3-43e4-9833-e3c9937197e0.wmv"
setup v1 option input-repeat=-1
setup v1 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v1,width=395,height=600}
new v2 broadcast enabled
setup v2 input "mmsh://mediaserver2.otn.ca/mediasite/070871fa-5b30-4e17-b83b-57b149044532.wmv"
setup v2 option input-repeat=-1
setup v2 output #mosaic-bridge{id=v2,width=395,height=600}


control bg play
control v1 play
control v2 play
```

VLC1.2 errors

```
[0xf80ec8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0xf4bb68] [Media: v1] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
[0xf7b578] [Media: v2] access_mms access error: cannot read data 2
[0xfd72f8] [Media: v2] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (WMA2)
[0xf72ed8] [Media: v1] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[0xf72ed8] [Media: v1] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried VLC 2.0 already?

The wiki by VLC should be updated to give you working examples with VLC 2: http://wiki.videolan.org/Mosaic

Concerning changes for your mosaic setup - with VLC 2 this would include the following

(1) You already replaced fake:// - to continuously show your image add:

```
    setup bg option image-duration=-1
```

(2) The mosaic options need to go with the command line as in:

```
    vlc -I telnet --mosaic-alpha=255 --mosaic-height=600 --mosaic-align=5 --mosaic-xoffset=0 [...] --vlm-conf /path/to/your/mosaic/config/file
```

(3) Transcode your bg broadcast and use the sub filter there:

```
   setup bg output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=h264,venc=x264{profile=baseline,level=30,aud},vb=768,width=800,height=600,scale=1}:standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.0.0.1:1234}
```

Hope this helps and points you in the right direction.